# Serialize objects for Dragboard content

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop, clipboard

**Problem:** I want to add some nonsymetric drag and drop between two different TreeTabelViews in JavaFX. That means I want to Copy when Dragging from A to B, dont want anything from B to A and I want Moving internaly.
My Code so far can be seen below. I know that this is just the tip of what is have to program but i cant even one "constraint" working.

```
public TreeTableRow<Task> internalMoveFactory(TreeTableView<Task> view) {
    TreeTableRow<Task> row = new TreeTableRow<>();
    row.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
        if (!row.isEmpty()) {
            Dragboard db = row.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
            db.setDragView(row.snapshot(null, null));
            ClipboardContent cc = new ClipboardContent();
            cc.put(ROW_INDEX, row.getIndex());
            MainController.clipboard = row.getTreeItem().getValue(); //I know this is not very nice... but what else should i do?
            db.setContent(cc);
            event.consume();
        }
    });

    row.setOnDragOver(event -> {
        Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
        if (acceptable(db, row)) {
            if (isInternal(db,row)) {
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
                event.consume();
            }
        }
    });

    row.setOnDragDropped(event -> {
        Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
        if (acceptable(db, row)) {
            if(isInternal(db,row)) {
                int index = (Integer) db.getContent(ROW_INDEX);
                TreeItem<Task> item = tree.getTreeItem(index);
                Task taskItem = tree.getTreeItem(index).getValue();
                item.getParent().getChildren().remove(item);
                taskItem.getParentTask().getChildTaskList().remove(taskItem);
                getTarget(row).getChildren().add(item);
                getTarget(row).getValue().getChildTaskList().add(taskItem);
                taskItem.setParentTask(getTarget(row).getValue());
                event.setDropCompleted(true);
                tree.getSelectionModel().select(item);
                event.consume();
            }
        }
    });
    return row;
}private boolean isInternal(Dragboard db,TreeTableRow<Task> row) {
    TreeTableView source = (TreeTableView) db.getContent(DRAG_SOURCE);
    boolean result = source == this.tree;
    return result;
}

private boolean acceptable(Dragboard db, TreeTableRow<Task> row) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (db.hasContent(ROW_INDEX)) {
        int index = (Integer) db.getContent(ROW_INDEX);
        if (row.getIndex() != index) {
            TreeItem<Task> target = getTarget(row);
            TreeItem<Task> item = tree.getTreeItem(index);
            result = !isParent(item, target);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// prevent loops in the tree
private boolean isParent(TreeItem parent, TreeItem child) {
    boolean result = false;
    while (!result && child != null) {
        result = child.getParent() == parent;
        child = child.getParent();
    }
    return result;
}
private TreeItem<Task> getTarget(TreeTableRow<Task> row) {
    TreeItem<Task> target = tree.getRoot();
    if (!row.isEmpty()) {
        target = row.getTreeItem();
    }
    return target;
}
```

My biggest problem is, that i cant serialize rows or task objects
(since the latter has StringProperties) to store them in the
`Dragboard`:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only serializable objects or ByteBuffer can be used as data with data format [application/test]
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumClipboard.putContentToPeer(QuantumClipboard.java:642)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumClipboard.flush(QuantumClipboard.java:269)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startDrag(QuantumToolkit.java:1224)
at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.dragDetectedProcessed(Scene.java:2953)
at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.process(Scene.java:3022)
at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.access$8200(Scene.java:2909)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3773)
```

**Question:** Is there any way to put objects to the clipboard without serializing them or storing them in a global variable? I simple want to get the Dragboard to store the source of the row (to know if it came from a different TreeTabelView) and the Task which I am dragging.

**Remarks:** I do know that I could just let Tasks extend TreeItem but this would lead to some weird constructs else where in the code.

Comment: ":Is there any way to put objects to the clipboard without serializing them or storing them in a global variable?" In short: no. Serialization is probably not what you want anyway, as I think you want a reference to the same `Task` instance: serializing to a clipboard and then deserializing on drop will (of course) create a new instance. Your best bet is some kind of global variable solution: you can create a simple class to hold the drag-drop state and dependency-inject a single instance of it into the classes that need it, if you want to avoid the pitfalls of the singleton pattern.

Comment: Also see [this](https://gist.github.com/james-d/a7202039b00170256293), if you really do want to use serialization.

Comment: If the nodes you want to drag data in between are in the same scene you could use `MouseDragEvent`s which allows you to access the gesture source. If you need data you cannot get from the gesture source node directly, you can easily store this data in the `userData` property or in the `properties` map of the node. This allows for arbitrary objects without the need for serialisation.

Comment: I dont know exactly what you mean fabian:
     row.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
            System.out.println(row.toString());
            System.out.println(event.getSource().toString());
This gives me expectedly the same output for each of the three events.

Comment: Interesting sidenote: If the TreeTableView B is empty (except of the hidden root node), there is no row to trigger Drag events...